# How to use JavaCameraView to capture a frame and send it to train the face recognizer?

Tags: android, opencv, camera, face-recognition

First, I've just started with android development last week so please be thorough in your explanations as I'm still a noob.

I've managed to create an app that uses the JavaCameraView to show the user what the back camera is seeing.  I created a new button in the activity bar to take a picture.  When the user clicks this button I want to capture that frame and then send it to the picture library I am using for the facerecognizer.  Thus far I haven't been able to succeed with this implementation.

So for the questions...

How can I capture a frame from the JavaCameraView when the take picture button is pressed?

From there do I just output the image to my image library using OutputStream?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

In your class you have to add `implements CvCameraViewListener2`. Now your class has a method `public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame cameraviewframe)`.